# How to connect activity_main layout file to a non Main activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to connect activity_main layout file to a google activity so as to allow the Speak method accessible to the activity_main file, how can it be done?

```
class googleSpeech : AppCompatActivity(), OnInitListener{   
    private var tts : TextToSpeech? = null;   
    private var speechBtn : Button? = null;    
    private var txt : EditText? = null;

    public fun spk(){    
        val Text = txt!!.text.toString()    
        tts!!.speak(Text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "")    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more info to show exactly what you want. If you are newbie in Android make sure naming layout with respect to Activity Name, does not mean you should inflate the layout inside the same named Activity

Comment: If you are asking about how to inflate inside activity, go through activity life-cycle. In short. inside onCreate method you can call setContentView function and pass your layout as an argument

Answer (score 0):

you can inflate any layout to an activity/fragment like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_main, container, false);
...
```